# How to Disable Any li From Being Sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I tried to set an `li` item with class `unsortable` not to be sortable in jQuery Sortable [plugin](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable), but it does not working at all.

From documentation link above said

> .sortable("disable")
>
> Disable all instantiated sortables in the set of matched elements

So, I tried this in my code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ol.example').sortable();
  $('ol.example li.unsortable').sortable('disable');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>

<ol class="example">
  <li class="unsortable">Option1 (unsorted)</li>
  <li>Option2</li>
  <li>Option3</li>
 </ol>
```

However, Option1 (unsortable) was sortable even thought I used `.sortable('disable')`.

What is incorrect for that how can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `disable` should be used for containers, but you can use `exclude`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ol.example').sortable({exclude: '.unsortable'});
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ol.example').sortable({exclude: '.unsortable'});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>

<ol class="example">
  <li class="unsortable">Option1 (unsorted)</li>
  <li>Option2</li>
  <li>Option3</li>
 </ol>
```